# Adding multiple endpoints into a Flask-RESTplus namespace from multiple files

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

I am working with Flask-Resplus API

I want to create multiple endpoints into a single namespace. That is simple, but if I want to split the code to add endpoints into multiple files, getting issues there.

Following is my app file:

```
from flask_restplus import Namespace, Api
from flask import Blueprint

from test_controller1 import test_ns


blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__)

api = Api(blueprint,
          title='Test API',
          version='1.0',
          description='Test API',
          )

api.add_namespace(test_ns, path='/test')
```

test_controller1.py

```
@test_ns.route("/test1")
class Test(Resource):
    def put(self):
        pass
```

test_controller2.py

```
from test_controller1 import test_ns

@test_ns.route("/test2")
class Test(Resource):
    def get(self):
        pass
```

If I import test_ns from test_controller_1, only test1 endpoint will be added in the namespace.

How can I add both the endpoints(available in different files) in the same namespace?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by defining Namespace(with the same name) across the classes.

test_controller1.py

```
test_ns1 = Namespace("test", "Namespace for test")
```

test_controller2.py

```
test_ns2 = Namespace("test", "Namespace for test")
```

Add both the namespaces to the blueprint.